# Unable to preview / run angular.js project from codenvy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp, codenvy

I developed an angular.js  project on codenvy IDE on Javascript framework ( or is it platform). I am unable to preview the same.

I get the following error.

`[ERROR] Failed to start application. : ====> /logs/stderr.log <==== node.js:134 throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick ^ Error: Cannot find module 'gulp' at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:326:11) at Function._load (module.js:271:25) at require (module.js:355:19) at Object.(/var/vcap.local/dea/apps/app-07zsn86eb8vspvg0-0-bf2638b3e702ededc5473a0c16608d37/app/gulpfile.js:1:74) at Module._compile (module.js:411:26) at Object..js (module.js:417:10) at Module.load (module.js:343:31) at Function._load (module.js:302:12) at Array. (module.js:430:10) at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:126:26)`

The console output says it cannot find Gulp, but my project certainly has gulp.js on the root folder. Also the project works perfectly fine when i preview this from a Webstorm editor - so i dont think there is an issue with the code per se..

Any help much appreciated

James

Answer (score 1):

If your project is public, please, share it with Codenvy's factory feature. So everyone will be able to look what is wrong with the project. (You can access factory on left panel of the IDE)